# Multiple if-statements with overwriting lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have the following piece of code in place that attempts to find matches within a list, based on a priority system:

```
possible_combinations = ["ABC", "AB", "A", "D"]


if len(possible_combinations) >= 1:
    chosen_combination = [comb for comb in possible_combinations if ("A" in comb) and ("C" in comb)]
    if (len(chosen_combination) == 0):
        chosen_combination = [comb for comb in possible_combinations if ("A" in comb)]
        if (len(chosen_combination) == 0):
            chosen_combination = [comb for comb in possible_combinations if ("C" in comb)]
            if (len(chosen_combination) == 0):
                raise ValueError(f"No match found.")
                
print(chosen_combination)

['ABC']
```

Is there any way I could refactor this code to get rid of these if-statements, and thereby make my code look nicer?

Comment: perhaps explain why/what, there might be completely different way to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
possible_combinations = ["ABC", "AB", "A", "D"]
combs = [("A","C"),("A",),("C",)]

for comb in combs:
    chosen_comb = [x for x in possible_combinations if all([y in x for y in comb])]
    if len(chosen_comb) > 0:
        break

print(chosen_comb)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this: `("A","C"),("A"),("C")` is your intent? The first parens make a tuple, and the second and third do not.

Comment: It doesn't really matter here, but you are right. What I meant was ```[("A","C"),("A",),("C",)]```. I corrected it.

Comment: Looks quite nice. Thx!